# Notification в определенное время суток

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте. Пишу приложение под Android на Java (в Android Studio). Появилась необходимость в ежедневном выводе нотификаций в определенное время суток. Пытался реализовать AlarmManager, который вызывает мои Notifications, но, увы, не выходит. Как мне правильно все это реализовать?

Как я описывал нотификацию:

```
public class NotificationMessage{

private static final String NOTIFICATION_TAG = "Message";

public static void notify(final Context context) {
    final Resources res = context.getResources();

    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(res.getString(R.string.enter_and_input_data))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentIntent(
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            context,
                            0,
                            new Intent(context, MainActivity.class),
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            )
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    notify(context, builder.build());
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR)
private static void notify(final Context context, final Notification notification) {
    final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_TAG, 0, notification);
    } else {
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_TAG.hashCode(), notification);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR)
public static void cancel(final Context context) {
    final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
        nm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_TAG, 0);
    } else {
        nm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_TAG.hashCode());
    }
}
```

}

Так вот, что мне нужно сделать что бы вызвать данную нотификацию в определенное время суток? (Было бы идеально, если бы предложили рабочий вариант кода, ибо "варианты из гугла", к несчастью не канают, то ли из-за "моих рук", то ли другой причине).

> а можно подробней, что конкретно у вас не вышло?

Не выходит вызвать мой notification. Пробовал при помощи AlarmManager:

```
  private void restartNotify() {
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationMessage.class);
    contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), contentIntent);
}
```

метод **restartNotify** подключал в **OnCreate** в **MainActivity**.
Результатов никаких не выдавало.

*Настройка времени для **AlarmManager***

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 15);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), contentIntent);
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: а можно подробней, что конкретно у вас не вышло?

Comment: Правил вопрос. Написал, что конкретно не вышло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы походу не понимаете как работает вся эта штука. А работает это так:

1. В назначенное время у вас `AlarmManager` должен стартовать `Intent` с бродкастом (широковещательным извещением) - это у вас есть.
2. По сути это означает что посылаемый бродкаст, который должен кем-то обрабатываться, а этого у вас нет. Бродкаст проваливается в пустоту и никем не обрабатывается.
3. В `onReceive` бродкастресивера надо вставить собственно вызов `notify`, который и поднимет нотификацию.

По русски выражаясь ваш класс `NotificationMessage` должен наследоваться от `BroadcastReceiver` и обрабатывать `onReceive`, при этом предварительно надо зарегистрировать ваш ресивер или в манифесте или вручную при запуске проги.

Надеюсь дальше уж сами разберетесь - код не дам :)

Comment: Благодарю! Все вышло, но 1 загвоздочка осталась. Как я понял, проблема во времени. То бишь, если в AlarmManager ставлю теперешнее время (System.currentTimeMillis()), все работает прелестно, но как только пытаюсь настроить свое точное время - ничего не выводиться.
 
Пример кода с настройкой времени приведу в "главном вопросе" выше. Подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: @Ингвар это уже другой вопрос. Оформите как положено. Если ответ вас устраивает пометьте его как понравившийся или принятый - здесь в форуме такие правила.

Comment: @Ингвар еще надо установить число, месяц и год. Или можно взять текущее время и прибавить нужное количество времени от текущего.

Comment: @Deadkenny, все. Проблему решил. Таки да, нужно было установить полностью и число, и месяц, и год. + Отредактировать небольшие нюансы.